# removeClass and then addClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click click on a div, that div is covered by a black line.

But when I click on any other div, I want the **old div to remove those black lines** and only the `current div` should have the border. Below is the code I am trying to follow:

```
var addDiv = document.getElementById("addDiv");

addDiv.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($(event.target).hasClass('context_menu')) {
    $(event.target).siblings('.clickedDiv').removeClass('clickedDiv');
    $(event.target).addClass('clickedDiv');
    console.log($(event.target).addClass('clickedDiv'));
  } else {
    $(event.target).parent().addClass('clickedDiv');
  }

  $("#ctxMenu").css({
    'top': event.pageY,
    'left': event.pageX
  }); // only this line to be added
  $("#ctxMenu").show();
}, false);

addDiv.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  $("#ctxMenu").hide();
}, false);
```

Above code is triggered on right click.

I want when I right click div with id `#addDiv` it should remove 'clickedDiv` class from everywhere and then proceed with the code to add the class on the clicked div.

**My html code:**

```
<div id="addDiv" [innerHtml]="divCode | noSanitize"></div>
<div id="ctxMenu" style="display:none">
  <ul id="ctxImage" style="display:none">
    <li (click)="clone()">Clone</li>
    <li (click)="changeImg()">Change Image</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "Remove `clickedDiv` from everywhere". Do you mean `#addDiv`?

Comment: updated my code, trying with this `$(event.target).siblings('.clickedDiv').removeClass('clickedDiv');`  but this line is not working

Comment: K so, I am still seeing that you're binding the `contextmenu` event only on `addDiv`. When your context says `when i click on any other div, i want the old div to remove those black lines and only the current div should have the border`. I think you should also post your html here

Comment: you can simply select all div containing class `clickedDiv` and add to `event.target` element. `$(".clickedDiv").removeClass("clickedDiv"); $(event.target).addClass("clickedDiv");`

Comment: I have updated the question with the html code

Answer (score 0):

Add a second class to all the divs and then remove the clickedDiv class from every member of the second class.

Something like:

```
$(".clickableDiv").on("contextmenu", function() {
    $(".clickableDiv").removeClass("clickedDiv");
    $(this).addClass("clickedDiv");
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="clickableDiv" id="div_1"></div>
<div class="clickableDiv" id="div_2"></div>
<div class="clickableDiv" id="div_3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to the following:

```
$("#addDiv").bind("contextmenu",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(event.target).hasClass('context_menu')){
        $(event.target).siblings('.clickedDiv').removeClass('clickedDiv');
        $(event.target).addClass('clickedDiv');
        console.log($(event.target).addClass('clickedDiv'));
}
else{
  $(event.target).parent().addClass('clickedDiv');
}

    $("#ctxMenu").css({'top':event.pageY,'left':event.pageX});   // only this line to be added
    $("#ctxMenu").show();
},false);

$('#addDiv').on("click",function(event){
    $("#ctxMenu").hide();
},false);
```

You should use `bind` and `on` to register the event listeners.

Comment: Add event listener line, please add, without it, it won't work

Comment: without this line ` addDiv.addEventListener("contextmenu",function(event){`  this is not working, on right click my menu not coming, can you come on team viewer

Comment: not working, let me know if you can take screenshare